# Best way at add date time stamp in directory of django image field

Tags: django, django-models

Till now i was using this function

```
def user_compressed_path(instance, filename):
    profile_pic_name = 'user/{0}/compressed/profile.jpg'.format(instance.id)
    full_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, profile_pic_name)
    if os.path.exists(full_path):
        os.remove(full_path)
    return profile_pic_name


def user_picture_path(instance, filename):
    profile_pic_name = 'user/{0}/picture/profile.jpg'.format(instance.id)
    full_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, profile_pic_name)
    if os.path.exists(full_path):
        os.remove(full_path)
    return profile_pic_name
```

i want path something like

```
'user/{0}/compressed/{1}/profile.jpg'.format(instance.id, date_time_stamp)
```

```
'user/{0}/picture/{1}/profile.jpg'.format(instance.id, date_time_stamp)
```

what should be the value of `date_time_stamp`

Comment: What is your exact problem here?

Comment: I want path something like user/{user.id}/{date}/{time}/profile.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
import datetime


date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
time = datetime.datetime.now().time()

def user_compressed_path(instance, filename):
    profile_pic_name = f'user/{instance.id}/{date}/{time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")}/profile.jpg'
    full_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, profile_pic_name)
    if os.path.exists(full_path):
        os.remove(full_path)
    return profile_pic_name
```

this will return output like this assuming if instance have id 2
`user/2/2021-12-12/10:45:09/profile.jpg`

Comment: Is this a good practice?

Comment: @RoyalBosS I don't know what is a good practice I just give you a solution in one way there many ways you can do this for that you have to search online or wait someone give better solution of your problem